# MongoDB : How to add a field that has an incremental number to collection with php-library?

Tags: php, mongodb

In the dosc of MongoDB php library,there is an example that `Update Many Documents`,as follow:
docs:  https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/tutorial/crud/#insert-many-documents

```
$collection = (new MongoDB\Client)->test->users;
$collection->drop();

$collection->insertOne(['name' => 'Bob', 'state' => 'ny', 'country' => 'us']);
$collection->insertOne(['name' => 'Alice', 'state' => 'ny']);
$collection->insertOne(['name' => 'Sam', 'state' => 'ny']);
$updateResult = $collection->updateMany(
    ['state' => 'ny'],
    ['$set' => ['country' => 'us']]
);
```

The example above adds a field thas has the same value.
I have an existing collction,it is like this:

```
  $categories =[
            ['_id' => ObjectId('xxx'),'category' => 'fruit'],
            ['_id' => ObjectId('xxx'),'category' => 'sport'],
            ['_id' => ObjectId('xxx'),'category' => 'book'],
            ['_id' => ObjectId('xxx'),'category' => 'animal'],
  ];
```

I will import it into mysql, I want to add a field `category_id` in MongoDB first.
the number is incremental and starts from `1`,and the result is like this:

```
$newCategories =[
        ['_id' => ObjectId('xxx'),'category' => 'fruit','category_id' =>1 ],
        ['_id' => ObjectId('xxx'),'category' => 'sport','category_id' =>2],
        ['_id' => ObjectId('xxx'),'category' => 'book','category_id' =>3],
        ['_id' => ObjectId('xxx'),'category' => 'animal','category_id' =>4],
 ];
```

How to do it with php-library?

Comment: Assign the number as you insert the data. There is no "oraclesque" ROWNUM functionality in MongoDB.

Comment: You could just let MySQL do that for you when you import the data?